# ClickListener in ScrollView intercepts scrolling

Tags: android

I have two rows of imageViews in a ScrollView. The imageViews all have onClickListener and when i want to scroll in this area it doesn't work. So i guess the Click listeners intercept the scrolling of the ScrollView. What's the best way to change this behaviour ?
My View hierarchy is like this:

```
<ScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

in the FrameLayout i put a Fragment which has a LinearLayout in which i inflate other LinearLayouts like this:

```
 productHolder.productLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: i think that is not the issue..click is less effective than scroll. It is just like when you touch the area(is scrolling) and after that you press there (is clicking).

Comment: Please show your code, because this is not usual behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) instead of an OnClickListener.

In the OnTouchListener you can check if the action of the motion event was a click and consume the event (return true). Otherwise you can leave the event for other listeners (return false) to consume.

Note, that you might need to add some additional implementation for figuring out which image view was clicked, however without seeing your layout, it's hard to give you a hint how to do it.